# How to display Meta tag description for Views genereated page

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

How to display meta tag description for Views generated page. Title is displaying by views but not description. Even I entered in Views description PFA.

Along with that I tried "[Metatag Views Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag_views_overview)" module that gives an error when I created new meta tag.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the `metatag_views` module, that already comes with the Metatag bundle. Once you install it, you will see a new section on the page where you edit views, and you can update description there.

The section is called "Metatags", and there you can override the defaults for a specific view.

Comment: I tried the same, I mean I installed the module metatag_views, that doesnt help me to get the description tag in the front end

Comment: I tested it before posting the reply. Did you try clearing the caches? Do you get any errors? What kind of view you are applying this on?

Comment: I had done as same u mentioned, cleared cache and no errors either. And it is "Content view".

Comment: Try doing this on a new view and see if you can replicate the issue.